# How to add error validation in Shopify User Registration Form?

Tags: html, forms, validation, shopify, registration

I have a user registration page in Shopify.

```html
{%- assign formId = 'RegisterForm' -%}
        {% form 'create_customer', id: formId, novalidate: 'novalidate' %}
          {% include 'form-status', form: form, form_id: formId %}
<div class="grid grid--half-gutters">
            <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-half">
          <label for="{{ formId }}-FirstName">{{ 'customer.register.first_name' | t }}</label>
          <input type="text" name="customer[first_name]" placeholder=" Enter First Name" id="{{ formId }}-FirstName" {% if form.first_name %}value="{{ form.first_name }}"{% endif %} autocomplete="given-name" required>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-half">
          <label for="{{ formId }}-LastName">{{ 'customer.register.last_name' | t }}</label>
          <input type="text" name="customer[last_name]" placeholder=" Enter Last Name" id="{{ formId }}-LastName" {% if form.last_name %}value="{{ form.last_name }}"{% endif %} autocomplete="family-name" required
                 {%- if form.errors contains 'last_name' -%}
              class="input--error"
              aria-invalid="true"
              aria-describedby="{{ formId }}-last_name-error"
            {%- endif -%}>
            {%- if form.errors contains 'last_name' -%}
            <span id="{{ formId }}-last_name-error" class="input-error-message">
              <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.accessibility.error' | t }} </span>
              {% include 'icon-error' %}
              <span>{{ form.errors.translated_fields['last_name'] | capitalize }} {{ form.errors.messages['last_name'] }}.</span>
            </span>
          {%- endif -%}
  </div>
        </div>
          <label for="{{ formId }}-email">{{ 'customer.register.email' | t }}</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            name="customer[email]"
            id="{{ formId }}-email" placeholder=" Enter Email"
            class="{% if form.errors contains 'email' %} input--error{% endif %}"
            {% if form.email %} value="{{ form.email }}"{% endif %}
            autocorrect="off"
            autocapitalize="off"
            autocomplete="email"
            aria-required="true"
            {%- if form.errors contains 'email' -%}
              class="input--error"
              aria-invalid="true"
              aria-describedby="{{ formId }}-email-error"
            {%- endif -%}
          required>
          {%- if form.errors contains 'email' -%}
            <span id="{{ formId }}-email-error" class="input-error-message">
              <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.accessibility.error' | t }} </span>
              {% include 'icon-error' %}
              <span>{{ form.errors.translated_fields['email'] | capitalize }} {{ form.errors.messages['email'] }}.</span>
            </span>
          {%- endif -%}

          <label for="{{ formId }}-password">{{ 'customer.register.password' | t }}</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            name="customer[password]"
            id="{{ formId }}-password" placeholder=" Enter Password"
            class="{% if form.errors contains 'password' %} input--error{% endif %}"
            aria-required="true"
            {%- if form.errors contains 'password' -%}
              class="input--error"
              aria-invalid="true"
              aria-describedby="{{ formId }}-password-error"
            {%- endif -%}
          required>
          {%- if form.errors contains 'password' -%}
            <span id="{{ formId}}-password-error" class="input-error-message">
              {% include 'icon-error' %}
              <span>{{ form.errors.translated_fields['password'] | capitalize }} {{ form.errors.messages['password'] }}.</span>
            </span>
          {%- endif -%}

          <div class="text-right register-bottom-links">
            <p><input type="submit"  class="submit btn" value="{{ 'customer.register.submit' | t }}" class="btn"></p>
            
          </div>
          {% endform %}
```

But only the email and password fields have validation. [Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/12mil08)
I want validation in FIRST NAME and LAST NAME input fields.
I don't add know what is the correct code.
I can't find any documentation on how to add error validation in Shopify User Registration Form.